# Using variables in the URL on wordpress menu link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress wp-admin to create the menu. It is under Appearance/menu.

I have a link that points to /members/ but what I really need is a link to /members/$logged_user...

For example /members/user_1 or /members/user_2.

How can I do that?
I dont know if it is important, but I am using buddypress plugin.

[image: Creating the menu item]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written  a short script for adding dynamic buddypress links in wordpress menu. Hope it helps

I have added custom links in wordpress menu replacing username in link with --username--
example
http://website_name.com/members/--username--/messages/

then add this code in function.php

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_override', 10, 3 );

function menu_override( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $newlink = str_replace("--username--", $user->user_login, $atts[href]);
    $atts[href] = $newlink;
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Concise and clean. WordPress doesn't support shortcodes in menu item urls because the brackets (i.e. `[`/`]`) are stripped out but it would be great to see support for an alternative implementation based on your approach. You should seriously consider fashioning this into a plugin. e.g. WordPress Menu URL Shortcodes

Comment: Thanks  but i believe in latest version of Wordpress. We have option of buddypress URL in wordpress menu by default

Comment: dude i was searching for something like this for 2 days 
buddy-press should nattily support this
i understand that they have login logged out links but whats needed is custom linking functions 
to make dynamic links to specific groups, specific profiles and message to host links

Answer (score 0):

The default menu doesn't really have that option. But you can make your own walker function, searching for the keyword and replacing it with the current user.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

But it would probably be faster and more manageable to just place the link outside the menu call with some static html and the needed php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BuddyPress Custom Profile Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-custom-profile-menu/) plugin to get close to this functionality, otherwise you will have to write custom code that uses actions/filters of `wp_nav_menu()`.